# How to match and replace the pattern [35+1] in vim version 7.4.160?

Tags: regular-expression

I have the file with below content:

```
char  abc[35+1];
char  abc[35+1];
[123];
char a_wo_011[35+1];
```

I want to replace the `[35+1]` with say `ABC`
But its not working.
I am able to search the pattern with below command:

```
/[35+1\]
```

But if I try to replace it , it is not working:

```
:%s/[35+1\]/ABC/
```

I even tried tripple \\ from other post.
Can you please advise what am I doing wrong and how to fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape `[` instead of `]` to indicate to Vim that you are not matching a collection of atoms but a litteral `[`

This should do the job:

```
%s/\[35+1]/ABC
```

See [`:h /collection`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2fcollection)

Comment: I tried everything but that. Thanks a lot for helping me. Will accept the answer after 5 minute limit. :) and thanks for explanation too

Comment: @ForeverLearner you should read :h magic, this will make it easier to avoid explicitly escaping characters with special meaning. For example /\V[35+1]/ would work